# scale and rotate matrices in transformation?

Tags: r, matrix, geometry, transformation, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of 2D points which i need to transform(2D) only and I know the boundaries of the transformed set. I am trying to put the points inside a restricted boundary. I am using R to do this transformation.

First I equate the boundary points of the original and transformed region. I am using scale and rotate matrix. So the equation would be:

newpoint = scale matrix * rotate matrix * original point.

Both scale matrix and rotate matrix are 2x2 matrices.

However when I do the above for my boundary points and get the rotate and scale matrix and then I use these two matrices to get the new bounded points for the set of original points, I am not able to restrict it within the boundary. Can somebody suggest what is going wrong?

In the below code, `xnewrange` is the boundary of the transformed points and `xorigrange` is the boundary of the original points and `myorigmat` is the matrix containing the original points which need to be transformed.

The code of what i have done so far is as below:

```
xnewrange<-c(-0.2588,4.036885)

ynewrange<-c(-2.653607,4.069070)

xorigrange<-c(-0.6810824,1.3324875)

yorigrange<-c(-1.419355,2.459154)

myorigmat
         [,1]       [,2]
31  1.3324875 -1.4193554
32  0.5755337  0.4543802
33 -0.3365769  1.0730593
34  0.8752970 -1.1013751
35 -0.6810824  0.9655893
36  0.2439643  0.1838974
37 -0.3893538  0.5326981
38  0.2241310  0.7273958
39 -0.1219151  0.2176043
40  0.8737421  2.4591542

coord<-matrix(c(xorigrange[1],xorigrange[2],yorigrange[1],yorigrange[2]),2,2,byrow=T)

trans_coord<-matrix(c(xnewrange[1],xnewrange[2],ynewrange[1],ynewrange[2]),2,2,byrow=T)

costheta<-sum(trans_coord[,1]*coord[,1])/(sqrt(sum((coord[1,1])^2,(coord[2,1])^2)) * sqrt(sum((trans_coord[1,1])^2,(trans_coord[2,1])^2)))               #using dot product

sintheta<-sqrt(1-(costheta^2))

rotate_mat<-matrix(c(costheta,sintheta,(-sintheta),costheta),2,2,byrow=T)

scale_mat<-(trans_coord) %*% solve(rotate_mat %*% coord)
```

Using the scale_mat and rotate_mat thus obtained to get the new points as follows:

```
newmat<-matrix(0,10,2)

for(i in 1:10){
newmat[i,]<-scale_mat %*% rotate_mat %*% matrix(c(mymat[i,1],mymat[i,2]),2,1,byrow=T)
}

newmat
```

But the points in newmat are not bounded within `xnewrange` and `ynewrange`.

Comment: Can you put the code of what you have done so far in?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative. Are you sure you've got them in the right order?

Comment: Ya i have taken care of the matrix multiplication. I have also added the code now.

Comment: I'm pre-coffee, so I may be missing something here, but: if you rotate and translate the corners of your original matrix (by hand, rather than via code), do you get the desired new corner locations? Try breaking the problem down into steps.  First rotate and verify the angles are correct.  Then translate so the leftmost point is at x=0, bottom-most at y=0, and observe the scalefactor required to 'fit' the opposite extrema.  Now check the intermediate values your code produces and see where the discrepancy occurs.

Comment: Thanks Carl.. I will try breaking it up into different steps... I tried rotating based on the centroids once. But it did not give me any fruitful result. I will try using the first corner and then the see if the second corner is working out well..

Comment: @Carl I have a doubt. You said try rotating, translating and then scaling but I dont know if it is the correct order. I think scaling, rotating and translating is the correct order. I also tried the way u suggested. It dint work out for me. I am not sure, may be I am missing something here.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it matters.  I just find it easier to see what's happening if I rotate and recenter, and then figure out what expansion/contraction is needed to fit inside the target region.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I got the answer. I used the same approach which you had suggested. Earlier I had done some small mistake. Now I am getting it properly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a<-c(-0.2588,-2.653607)

b<-c(-0.6810824,-1.419355)

costheta<-sum(a*b)/((sqrt(sum((a[1]^2),(a[2]^2))))*(sqrt(sum((b[1]^2),(b[2]^2)))))

sintheta<-sqrt(1-(costheta^2))

m1output_corner<-matrix(c(a[1],a[2]),2,1)

m1input_corner<-matrix(c(b[1],b[2]),2,1)

rotate_mat<-matrix(c(costheta,sintheta,(-sintheta),costheta),2,2,byrow=T)

mint<-rotate_mat %*% m1input_corner

tran<-matrix(c(-mint[1,1],-mint[2,1]),2,1)

m2output_corner<-matrix(c(4.036885,4.069070),2,1)

m2input_corner<-matrix(c(1.332488,2.459154),2,1)

smat<- m2output_corner / ((rotate_mat%*% m2input_corner)+tran)

scalemat<-matrix(c(smat[1,1],0,0,smat[2,1]),2,2,byrow=T)


newmat<-matrix(0,10,2)

for(i in 1:10){

  newmat[i,]<-(scalemat %*% ((rotate_mat %*% matrix(c(mymat[i,1],mymat[i,2]),2,1,byrow=T)) + tran ))

}

newmat
```

Comment: when you edit, please don't add blank lines.  And to make the code readable,  select the entire code block and hit <CTRL>-K (or <CMD>-K on a Mac) to format it nicely.